# SELECT where clause (multiple values in multiple columns)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following select statement. What I am basically trying to do is select all rows where the manager and year are equal to what is shown in the sql below and the columns fcst_jan through fcst_dec does not contain one of those values. It seems to work find for some, but I am still getting rows that contain 205 in one of the columns. So basically i want to select rows where any column jan through dec doesnt contain one of those values. Please help. I can't figure it out. I know my table design isnt the best way of doing it, but it is what I have, so i need to figure it out.  I am on SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT [fcst_id]
      ,[fcst_emplname]
      ,[fcst_emplid]
      ,[fcst_posid]
      ,[fcst_mgrid]
      ,[fcst_sect_id]
      ,[fcst_year]
      ,[fcst_jan]
      ,[fcst_feb]
      ,[fcst_mar]
      ,[fcst_apr]
      ,[fcst_may]
      ,[fcst_jun]
      ,[fcst_jul]
      ,[fcst_aug]
      ,[fcst_sep]
      ,[fcst_oct]
      ,[fcst_nov]
      ,[fcst_dec]
      ,[fcst_comments]
  FROM [EMS].[dbo].[TEMSFCST]
  where fcst_mgrid='00809571' and fcst_year=2016 and 
  (
  fcst_jan not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or 
  fcst_feb not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or 
  fcst_mar not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or 
  fcst_apr not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or 
  fcst_may not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or 
  fcst_jun not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or
  fcst_jul not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or 
  fcst_aug not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or 
  fcst_sep not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or
  fcst_oct not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or 
  fcst_nov not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or 
  fcst_dec not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211)
  )
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here, you just need to change the `or` to `and`

Comment: On a side note this seems like a poor schema / table design. Better would be to have a table with a date column (or an int representing the  month if year does not matter) and a value column and then a FK column that links back to your `temsfcst` table.

Comment: Yes, i know it is poor, but it is what i have.  If I use and, then i get no rows.  So it is filtering out rows that have a 1 and 5 in it, but for some reason they dont always work

Comment: Can you show sample data where you would return rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain records that doesn't have these values (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) in any month column:

```
(
fcst_jan not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or 
fcst_feb not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) or 
...
)
```

you should change 'or' by 'and', otherwise if one record has fcst_jan=25 and fcst_feb=205, it will appear in the final result.

```
(
fcst_jan not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) and
fcst_feb not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211) and
...
)
```

Comment: If I use 'and' then no records are returned.

Comment: maybe none record match this criteria: fcst_mgrid='00809571' and fcst_year=2016 and any_month not in (1,2,3,4,5,205,211)

Comment: No, there are, for that i am sure.